# how to send the url post using httpclient

Tags: java, spring-mvc, reflection, apache-httpclient-4.x

i login to my project like the following using httpclient :

```
public void login(String username,String password){
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check");
        try {
          List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", username));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", password));

          post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```

and i use the above like the following :

```
HttpClientRequests httpRequest = new HttpClientRequests();
httpRequest.login("mayank","hexgen");
```

now i want to send a `POST` request for method which is there like the following :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/trade/createrequisition")
    public @ResponseBody
    void createRequisition(@RequestBody CreateRequisitionRO[] request,
            @RequestHeader("validateOnly") boolean validateOnly) {
....
}
```

so i have created reflection like the following :

```
HttpClientRequests httpRequest = new HttpClientRequests();
        Class[] paramString = new Class[1]; 
        paramString[0] = String.class;

        Class parames = CreateRequisitionRO[].class;

        CreateRequisitionRO[] roRqequest = new CreateRequisitionRO[1];
        boolean istrueOrFalse=true;


        Class booleanVal ;  
        booleanVal = Boolean.TYPE;

        Class cls;
        try {
            cls = Class.forName("com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI");

            Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("createRequisition", parames,booleanVal);

            RequestMapping methodRequestMappingAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
            RequestMethod[] methods = methodRequestMappingAnnotation.method();
            String[] mappingValues = methodRequestMappingAnnotation.value();
            //String methodType = methods[0].name();
            //String url = mappingValues[0];

            httpRequest.login("mayank","hexgen");

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

now after this `httpRequest.login("mayank","hexgen");` how to send request to access the following method :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/trade/createrequisition")
        public @ResponseBody
        void createRequisition(@RequestBody CreateRequisitionRO[] request,
                @RequestHeader("validateOnly") boolean validateOnly) {
    ....
    }
```

So.

I am able to login to the system programatically but not able to call after successful login.

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of content the service can accept. Xml/json/whatever?

I see you get the address where you have to post via reflection. The content you should post to that address is a `CreateRequisitionRO` array marshalled to json/xml(?). Once you have them marshalled, simply send the post message with that conent set as request entity. The server side should then unmarshall the request content and invoke the `createRequisition()` handler method.

How the marshalling is done depends on your project. There are many libraries for that, JAXB being the most prevalent, I guess.